# MySQL no retornar datos en una columna

Tags: c#, mysql, base-de-datos, net

Tengo una base de datos dónde en ocasiones no hay datos en algunas columnas, quisiera saber cómo podría saber que esa columna es `null`.

He probado con

```
  if(!_Rellenar.HasRows) { isNull = false; }
```

Y con:

```
  if(!_Rellenar.Read()) { isNull = false; }
```

Pero en ninguno de los dos casos funciona. Estoy segura de que en dichas columnas, la base de datos está vacía, así que no logro comprender por que puedo hacer `Read()` y `HasRows()` sin que me devuelva `False`.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenendo en cuenta que `_Rellenar` es del tipo `MySqlDataReader` no pede preguntar en este por una columan, ya que este representa al registro completo

Si vas a preguntar por una columna usarias

```
MySqlDataReader _Rellenar = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if(_Rellenar.Read()){

     if(_Rellenar["nombreColumna"] != DBNull.Value){
         var contenido = Conver.ToString(_Rellenar["nombreColumna"]);
      }

}
```

algo como eso aplicarias para conocer si la columna contiene un valor null o no

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias! :)